# How to fix and reshape messed up shapes in sculpt mode

Tags: edit-mode, sculpting, dynamic-topology, sculpt

i’m trying to get more into sculpting. While doing so, i’m sculpting a fetus model. During that, i lost my attention to the hands. Now that i am in Dyntopo mode already, i need to fix the hands:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Using the Grab Brush alone makes things even worse. It is also very difficult to mask out all the rest of the sculpture. And mesh editing in Edit mode is almost impossible due to the Dyntopo mesh.

What would be the best strategy to fix the hands?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to fix with the hands? From what I understand after reading your question, I assume you want to fix the right hand of the fetus since there are only four fingers, right?

If the fingers were the problem then I would go ahead and delete them. I would then create new geometry to fill up the holes where there used to be the fingers ( using the boolean operator Union to join the new geometry to the fetus's hand). After that, I would use the "snake hook" brush to pull out new fingers (enable Dyntopo when doing this step so that the brush can pull out enough geometries to form new fingers).

Answer (score 0):

To fix the hand, there is an addon that will make this very easy for you :) THe addon exists for Blender 2.79 and 2.8.

https://blenderartists.org/t/mask-tools/642502/38

https://github.com/bookyakuno/-Blender-/blob/master/maskTools_2-8.zip

This will allow you to create a vertex group of the body and hand, and mask them off separately in the sculpt room.

I hope this helps. Cheers!